# Хранилище паролей на с++

Tags: c++, база-данных, хранилище

Всем привет! 
Это мой первый вопрос на сайте, так что не судите строго, пожалуйста.
Если описать мою проблему кратко, то я хочу создать собственное хранилище паролей на подобии KeePass в рамках школьного проэкта (аналог курсовой работы). Наибольшая проблема заключается в том, что я - ученик 9 класса физико-технического лицея и пока что не обладаю достаточным объёмом знаний для самостоятельной реализации такого проэкта. Я не знаю, с чего начать решение этой проблемы, пока что из языков прогаммирования знаком только с С++ и немного с чистым С.
Логика приложения на Винде такая: рядовой юзер запускает приложение, вводит достоточно сильный пароль и логин на своё усмотрение, приложение его не пускает с паролем по типу 12345 и просит ввести ещё раз. Его предупреждают о том, что при потере этого пароля данные вернуть невозможно. Затем он попадает в основную часть приложения, где он может хранить в виде интерактивной таблицы свои пароли и логины. Видимый пароль не показывается как 12345, а, например, как *****. Но при копировании он снова приобритает вид 12345.  Идея приложения в том, чтобы создать относительно (в меру моих возможностей и ресурсов) безопасное хранилище данных, с простым и понятным для юзера интерфейсом и не сильно сложным алгоритмом защиты данных.
[image: Вот такой интерфейс]
Буду рад всем идеям и предложениям, возможно готовым решениям, из которых можно подчерпнуть идеи (никакой копипасты, проверку на анти-плагиат тогда точно не пройдёт, да и не честно это) особенно советам, с чего лучше начать.

Comment: Разбейте задачу на части и решайте каждую из них. Если вы хотите делать графический интерфейс, наверно, надо сначала разобраться с основами написания GUI на C++, почитать учебники, курсы в Интернете. По мере изучения основ реализовывайте необходимый интерфейс, ищите ответы и задавайте вопросы по проблемным местам.Дальше у вас возникнут какие-то новые цели, с ними тоже надо будет разбираться.

Comment: Если с не слишком сложным алгоритмом защиты данных, то храните все в текстовом файле, который шифруйте XOR-ом  мастер-паролем (зашит в коде программы). При чтении в память вы расшифровываете, при записи -- переписываете весь файл шифрованными данными. Для представления в текстовом виде в файле примените дополнительно кодирование данных в BASE64

Comment: лучше взять не с++ а c# проблем меньше будет. копировать пароль очень плохая идея

Answer (score 2):

Первое и самое главное Вам нужно декомпозировать задачу.

Примерный план того как бы я стал делать на вашем месте, я так понимаю планируется наличие GUI:

1. Подготовка

   - Выбрать на чём его реализовывать. Я советую QT он лучше всего задокументирован и прост в разработке.
   - Примерно нарисовать какие окна и что они делают хотя бы на листе бумаге.
   - Разобраться где и как вы будете хранить данные(пароли) наиболее распространенный вариант sqlite3 база, файл которой будет шифроваться мастер паролем.
   - Так же как с  GUI прикинуть какие таблицы вам понадобятся и зарисовать это.
   - Выбрать алгоритмы для шифрования как самих паролей, с учётом что они должны расшифровываться в нормальный текст так и всего файла БД.
2. Реализация

   - Разобраться как писать и читать в выбранную вами БД.
   - Разобраться как шифровать и дешифровать данные.
   - Накидать GUI в редакторе
   - Сделать базовую логику переходов (открытие нужных окон по кнопкам)
   - Воспроизвести и соединить всё части в коде.

П.С.

Возможно вы уже знаете что такое GitLab но на случай скажу про него. Создаёте и ведите в нем свой проект. А для того что бы продвигаться и не потеряться в большом количестве задач, возьмите каждую из выше перечисленных задач и разбейте на более мелкие которые можете решить за приемлемые сроки  опишите их как отдельные задачи(issue). Так вы сможет отслеживать свой прогресс.

П.П.С.

Если вы со всем этим справитесь можете смело писать резюме и устраиваться junior разработчиком. Удачи)